Why is there no option for User's collection when I'm trying to add firestore rules in FlutterFlow

This is my users collection and I have already populated it with sample data. However looking up on a youtube  tutorial and the document I am supposed to be using Users collection so only users can edit their own profile. However there is no such option when I tried to do for my own project. Is there a way I can add it so only users can edit their own info etc?
I tried deleting my collection and renaming it into users instead of user but was unable to see the Users collection option either. The documents also told me this Users Collection: Allow users whose authentication id is the same as the id of a document. Tip: This option is only applicable to a 'users' collection.

Did you implement Firebase Authentication? If yes, did you try to restrict the access based on the that?

I think my firebase authentication set up but however I cant seem to validate it even though the database in my firebase is correct

How did you try to validate the auth in the rules?
